# Command line argument javafx

Tags: java, javafx, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a simple program to plot a line graph using javafx.

I have the following code:

```
public class Plot extends Application {
  public void start(Stage stage){

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to pass a .csv file as a command line argument when running the program. And access the file from within:

```
 public void start(Stage stage){
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getParameters()` method from the Application class ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--)).

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // for example list all given parameters
        getParameters().getRaw().forEach(System.out::println);
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```